# What is paging and why is it important

Tags: linux, unix, paging

The manpage states: 
pgpgin/s - Total number of kilobytes the system paged in from disk per second.

pgpgout/s - Total number of kilobytes the system paged out to disk per second.

fault/s - Number of page faults (major + minor) made by the system per second. This is not a count of page faults that generate I/O, because some page faults can be resolved without I/O.

majflt/s - Number of major faults the system has made per second, those which have required loading a memory page from disk

Why is it a bad thing if PageIn Rate is above threshold range? Does this mean that said application is pulling in to much memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Computer operating system, Memory management is crucial aspect. Paging is one of the memory management plan by which computer stores and retrieves data from the secondary storage to the main memory of the device.
The secondary storage is divided into pages for storing and retrieving data.
Paging is an important part of virtual memory implementation.

You can also go through the following links to get more details:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging
http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&obj=page&pageid=89

Comment: Great Resource, Shivaraj. Thank you!

Comment: @Chris Please accept the answer if it was useful and upvote. :-)